# Why is the videoview so slow?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I put a videoview in my application and it works fine but when you open up the page it take forever for it to load/buffer.

Is there anyway I can fix this. I mean it's a *3 second video*. It shouldn't take a long time to load. Right?

code:

```
 package jslsoftware.co.nr;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    import android.widget.MediaController;

    public class videoview1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video1);

        Uri vidFile = Uri.parse("http://jslserver1.yolasite.com/resources/3gp_videos/Animal.3gp");
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly placing the code why not subclass it?

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Just replace your stuff inside doInBackground method. If you have anything to do after it's executed place in onPostExecute.

Comment: I read the That link and it makes a lot of sense in the way of not bogging things down. But right now I'm not very good with code (just starting out). Would you be able to supply me with some code that uses a separate thread or give me instructions on what I need to do to install that into my code. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Define another class inside your code and place your video calling in the do background services. I will be editing my answer with the code.

Comment: videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile); must be done in the UI thread. That is by far the slowest call in this. On Google TV that call alone can cause UI not to respond.. :(

Comment: I don't know if this answer really answer the question. It's seem not related to me. The question is about the buffer/loading inside the video player is very slow.