# How can VideoView be made faster to load?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, android-videoview

`VideoView` takes longer to start playing videos compared to iOS `AVPlayer` and WP `MediaElement`. The last two are almost always instantenous in my case, but `VideoView` takes anywhere between 5 and 15 seconds to start streaming. Are there any tips and tricks to speed it up? I'm setting up video streaming in a way similar to this: [Why is the videoview so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082728/why-is-the-videoview-so-slow)

I'm not an Android expert, but I remember reading `VideoView` internally calls prepare async, so I'm not sure how a separate background task helps. I also noticed YouTube videos on my S6 take longer to open than YouTube on iOS. However, YouTube on S6 is still faster than my naive implementation, so I don't know what I don't know.

Are there any 3rd-party implementations faster than `VideoView`?

Comment: hi. this depend on Core Android API and something as: what is your device ? it really strong phone ?  Size or quality (HD or fullHD) of your video ? You can try Vitamio which is a C++ video controller lib

Comment: To give you context, I'm testing it on S6. The video is not HD and is only 10 seconds long. I'd say the server is fast enough since other devices load the video quickly.

Comment: try ExoPlayer library... may be you can decrease some loading time...

Comment: ExoPlayer looks promising. Any examples showing how to use it with a UI?